# Progress Bar not showing while waiting for Future to complete

Tags: android, asynchronous, future

I'm writing some code to discover the different ways of handling asynchronisity in Android, and I've already done AsyncTask, now I've had some luck with futures in the past, but this time it's bugging me a bit...

The code itself works fine, except for the fact that the (spinning) progressbar only shows up after the download operation has completed... despite the fact that I tell the code to display it before...

here's the code:

```
public void startDownload(final String url) {
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // progress bar should appear here

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Future<String> promise = pool.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            String response = "";
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

                String s = "";

                while((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) response += s;

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }
    });


    while(promise.isDone() == false) {
        // wait
    }

    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // and disappear here

    try {
        GitHubStatus status = gson.fromJson(promise.get(), GitHubStatus.class);

        statusText.setText(status.getStatus());
        bodyText.setText(status.getBody());
        dateText.setText(status.getCreationDate());
    } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    // instead it briefly appears here, and then disappears again
}
```

For those who don't know; futures execute themselves, and thus you don't need to call a "run"or "start" method to start it

I've tried to put a `Log.v("DEBUG: ", "Loading...");` in the loop that waits for it to finish, and it does print the message just fine, many times at that

I've tried without the loop, that doesn't work either, and I've even tried with a `ProgressDialog` that doesn't work either...

I understand that I can't update the UI thread while the UI thread is busy, but I only set the visibility before and after any of the work in the UI thread is being done, so what's wrong here? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Please, show your layout file.

Comment: My layout file is irrelevant in this, I know the progessbar appears where it should, it's just not appearing when it should

Comment: People should really stop asking for stuff that has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: @Ascorbin who are you referring to? me or Ranko?

Comment: I was referring to Ranko asking for the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
public void startDownload(final String url) {
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // progress bar should appear here

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Future<String> promise = pool.submit(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            String response = "";
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

                String s = "";

                while((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) response += s;

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    bar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // and disappear here

                    try {
                        GitHubStatus status = gson.fromJson(promise.get(), GitHubStatus.class);

                        statusText.setText(status.getStatus());
                        bodyText.setText(status.getBody());
                        dateText.setText(status.getCreationDate());
                    } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
                        ee.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });     
            return response;
        }
    });
}
```

Because of

```
while(promise.isDone() == false) {
            // wait
        }
```

You are blocking UIThread.

Comment: But isn't the Future supposed to do its thing in the background? in a separate thread I mean... by that definition it wouldn't block the UI thread... But instead the UI thread just hangs until it finishes executing the Future, even without the loop... Why is that? Shouldn't the progressbar become visible anyway? I mean I set the visibility before I start the download...

Comment: also with the code you're showing, you're trying to access the future from within itself...

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.
Future is asynchronous, but using methods like `get()` and `isDone()` can block. Even when it does, shouldn't the `ProgressBar` or `ProgressDialog` be showing? Just like in an `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

`FutureTask` can be used to run asynchronous tasks. However, it's `get()` method and `isDone()` method will block when called.

Thus, when you try to show a `ProgressBar` on the UI thread that has just been blocked by `FutureTask`, it won't show, till probably after the `FutureTask` is done.
In your case, your start the `ProgressBar` before initiating the `FutureTask` call, which is correct, but once `FutureTask` starts, running of the `ProgressBar` is blocked.

To solve this, you can run a `FutureTask` inside an `AsyncTask`:

- Use the `onPreExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask to show the` ProgressBar`.
- Use the `onProgressUpdate()` method of the `AsyncTask` to update the progress on the `ProgressBar`.
- Use the `onPostExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask` to hide the `ProgressBar`; in a worst case scenario, you can call `runOnUiThread()` inside the `FutureTask`'s `Callable`/`Runnable`, to hide the `ProgressBar`.